# Improving mobile aps client server communication efficiency and data availability in offline mode

Tags: angularjs, cordova, offline-caching, data-synchronization, offlineapps

My question is about how to store data which once was received online and still can be processed after the mobile device got offline and/or was restarted.
I'm using AngularJS with Ionic (PhoneGap) for building apps. But my question is not explicitly adressing these technologies.

Best practices, patterns or algorythms would be very helpful to me or even some useful articles or key words.

1) The most simple challenge is to make my app more user-friendly by making its functionality usable not only if the device is online but also in offline mode. In my case this implies that I have to make the last fetched online data available for later use (while device is offline and also after restarting the device!).

2) A bit more difficult is to reduce the communication costs by only **synchronizing** the server side changed data when the device reconnects to the internet.

3) Entities can also be produced on client side while the device is offline and they must get synchronized to the server too. There are no potential risks of conflicts because the users don't share Entities with write access.

4) I use Googles and Apples push services to inform the devices about newer  entity versions, which should get updated on client side. So polling isn't needed.

*Client side technologies:* Javascript, AngularJS Framework, Ionic Framework, SQLite (WebSQL) or IndexedDB, PhoneGap (Cordova)

*Server side technologies:* Java EE, JPA, MySQL

*Data Format and communication:* JSON over REST / http, Googles and Apples push services for server-to-client messaging

Comment: That may be 'closed' as too broad, but i will 'fave' it myself to see what wise colleagues may suggest. I'm exactly at that place for one of my apps :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Store the needed data inside a local SQLite database, and pull it out when the app starts/resumes.

---

2)In the MySQL database you need a table that creates new entries when you update/change/create content. You would need to store an id and a timestamp (maybe a boolean value if the content was deleted).

On the device you would make a request to the server to send the data from that table and compare it with the locally stored data. If there is a new id or the timestamp has change make a new request to pull the updated data.

---

3)Store the created data locally with a flag that it isn't synced with the server. When the device then goes online again check for not synced flags and send the data to the server with an identifier to know which device it comes from and where to save it.

---

4)See 2)

You could make a Java script which checks every x minutes for updated entries and send an automatic push Notification with it. What you would need is 2 tables, one with the newest updates and one with the updates that got pulled by the device(just id's and timestamps, not all the data).

---

I hope this was helpful, if something new comes to my mind I will update this answer.